# Godel's second incompleteness theorem for non-r.e. theories

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, proof-theory

R. Jeroslow in this [paper](http://philpapers.org/rec/JERELA-2) proves that a non-recursively enumerable theory whose set of theorems is $\Delta_2$-definable may prove consistency of itself
but it can not prove 2-consistency of itself.

**Question.**  Are there any generalization of these results (or some similar results) for theories which are $\Sigma_n$, $\Delta_n$ or $\Pi_n$ definable ?

Comment: What is 2-consistency? Do you mean $\text{Con}(\text{Con}(T))$? Or perhaps $\text{Con}(\text{PA}+\text{Con}(T))$ or $\text{Con}(T+\text{Con}(T))$, or something else?

Comment: Jeroslow says that a theory $H$ is 2-consistent if there does not exist any $\Sigma_2^0$ sentence $\psi = (\exists x)(\forall y) R(x,y)$ such that $\psi$ is a theorem of $H$, and such that for all numerals $n$, $\neg (\forall y) R(\ulcorner n\urcorner, y)$ is also a theorem of $H$.  Thus, if $H$ is 2-inconsistent, in particular $H$ cannot be sound for $\Sigma_2^0$ sentences, since $H$ states that $\psi$ is true and then goes and provides counterexamples to every possible instance of $(\forall y) R(\ulcorner n\urcorner, y)$.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins : Yes , In other words 2-consistency is $\omega$-consistency restricted to $\Sigma_2$ formulas.

Comment: Isn't that simply $\Sigma_2$-soundness?

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek : Yes, it can be proved that it is equal to $\Sigma_2$ soundness, but by a result of Kriesel, 3-consistency is not equal to $\Sigma_3$-soundness (see [reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.philosophy.ox.ac.uk%2F__data%2Fassets%2Fpdf_file%2F0015%2F1194%2FSufficient_conditions.pdf&ei=7DAPVczxCoXfaqD_glg&usg=AFQjCNFrPLZT7E00XZ5-GjdmzvJ2Lwoqzw))